# NDB Cluster TCP/IP Connections Using Direct Connections

Tags: mysql, tcp, mysql-cluster, ndb

I'm using MySQL Cluster Manager for my NDB Cluster.
[image: My NDB Cluster]

I want to   setup direct TCP connections between two nodes (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-cluster-excerpt/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-tcp-definition-direct.html). I have set up correctly two ndbtmd nodes by command:

```
set NodeId1:ndbmtd:1+ndbmtd:2=1,NodeId2:ndbmtd:1+ndbmtd:2=2,HostName1:ndbmtd:1+ndbmtd:2=192.168.1.2,HostName2:ndbmtd:1+ndbmtd:2=192.168.1.3 mycluster;
```

[image: Config.ini file]

But when I want to connect two mysqld nodes by TCP direct connections I'm not able to do this.

```
set NodeId3:mysqld:51+mysqld:52=51,NodeId4:mysqld:51+mysqld:52=52,HostName3:mysqld:51+mysqld:52=192.168.1.2,HostName4:mysqld:51+mysqld:52=192.168.1.3 mycluster;
```

The problem is that MySQL Cluster Manager is creating config.ini file automatically based on set options in MySQL Cluster Manager so I can't change config.ini file manually. Is it possible to connect two mysqld nodes by TCP direct connections? If it's possible, how can I connect two mysqld nodes by TCP direct connections?

Answer (score 0):

You can not connect two mysqld nodes with each other in Ndb cluster.

In Ndb cluster there are no connections between mysqld nodes.
mysqld only connects to management servers and data nodes.

Other ports and connections for MySQL servers not related to Ndb (for example MySQL replication) are not configured via config.ini.

Comment: If there would been mysqld-mysqld connections, one should use  NodeId1, NodeId2, HostName1, HostName2 also when configure that connection.  Not NodeId3, NodeId4, HostName3, HostName4.  But that was not the question.